# tensorflow is really slow with 16 GPU and get stuck

Tags: python, tensorflow, amazon-ec2, nvidia

I am using amazon EC2 with 16 GPU to do calculations.
When I configured everything I needed and tested it in python, something strange happened.

Follwing are some experiments:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import time
a=time.time()
hello=tf.constant('hello')
sess=tf.Session()
```

After the above I got a very long message:

```
2018-01-31 07:10:27.922290: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2018-01-31 07:10:27.922347: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2018-01-31 07:10:27.922360: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2018-01-31 07:10:27.922371: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2018-01-31 07:10:27.922381: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use FMA instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2018-01-31 07:11:05.263488: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:893] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2018-01-31 07:11:05.265392: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:955] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: Tesla K80
major: 3 minor: 7 memoryClockRate (GHz) 0.8235
pciBusID 0000:00:0f.0
Total memory: 11.17GiB
Free memory: 11.10GiB
2018-01-31 07:11:05.487461: W tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:523] A non-primary context 0x56312fdf3970 exists before initializing the StreamExecutor. We haven't verified StreamExecutor works with that.
2018-01-31 07:11:05.488072: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:893] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2018-01-31 07:11:05.489826: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:955] Found device 1 with properties: 
name: Tesla K80
major: 3 minor: 7 memoryClockRate (GHz) 0.8235
pciBusID 0000:00:10.0
Total memory: 11.17GiB
Free memory: 11.10GiB
2018-01-31 07:11:05.707955: W tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:523] A non-primary context 0x56312fdf7e80 exists before initializing the StreamExecutor. We haven't verified StreamExecutor works with that.
2018-01-31 07:11:05.708452: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:893] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2018-01-31 07:11:05.709916: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:955] Found device 2 with properties: 
name: Tesla K80
major: 3 minor: 7 memoryClockRate (GHz) 0.8235
pciBusID 0000:00:11.0
Total memory: 11.17GiB
Free memory: 11.10GiB
```

On and on......

It seems that tensorflow is scanning the GPU devices.
But this is very slow. I waited for 5 minutes to see the above and later it got stuck till an automatic disconnection from amazon.
Before when I did the same thing in my lab server which has 4 tesela k40 everything went well.

Does anybody know why this happened?

Comment: Ask to `amazon EC2` service ! You're using a locked processor. We don't have access to some critical processor architectures. I think the firm pays for the electricity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trial and error I finally sovled the issue.
I uninstalled everything and reinstalled NVIDIA driver deb file BUT installed it using the command:

```
sudo apt-get install XXX
```

Then use Anaconda to install accelerate and tensorflow.
Later install CUDA according to the standard procedure.